# Using Ajax to send data to a Django model

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, post

I created the following Ajax request to send data to my views.py. Once the request is sent, the view should save thata in my database. The problem with my actual code is that the value that i submit in the form, is not being saved.

Here is what i tried:
**Html/JS**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#test").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajtest/",
      data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
            state:"inactive",
        data: $('#test').serialize(),
      },
      success: function () {
        $('#message').html("<h2>Submitted.</h2>")
      }
    });
    return false; 
  });

});
</script>

<form method='post' id='test'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text">
  <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
  <div id='message'>Initial text</div>
</form>
```

And here is the **view**:

```
def ajtest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        model = MyModel()
        model.value = request.POST['data']
        model.user = request.user
        model.save()

        messages.success(request, f"Success!!")

    else:
        messages.success(request, f"Error")
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Here, `user` is being saved. I see a new record appearing in the DB when i hit the Ajax form, the problem is that, in the column `value` i'm not seeing the data submitted in the form, but instead i'll see either a blank field or, now, the CSRF token of the request. Can someone help me find the problem? I'm sure it is in the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code snippet.

```
<script>
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=",
     decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
     ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
     for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
       return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
 }


  // Generic Function to process Ajax Calls
  function callAJAX(url, header, parameters, req_type, successCallback, 
    beforeSendCallback, completeCallback ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    type : req_type,
    url : url,
    headers : header ,
    data :  parameters,
    beforeSend : beforeSendCallback,
    complete : completeCallback,
    success : successCallback,
    error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log( 'error' + textStatus + ' ' + xhr + ' ' + errorThrown );
    },
    async: false
  });
 }


 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").submit(function (event) {
        callAJAX( "/ajtest",
         {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
         parameters={'data': $('#text_box').val()},
        'post',
         function(data){
           $('#message').html("<h2>Submitted.</h2>");

         }, null, null );
 return false; 
});


 });
</script>

<form method='post' id='test'>
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" id='text_box' name='input_val'>
 <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
<div id='message'>Initial text</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, could you please explain with the first two functions? What are getCookie and callAJAX doing?

Comment: @jack022,  both are   generic functions to get cookie from html document and ajax call.

Comment: Tried this. Here is the response from my django view: MultiValueDictKeyError at /ajtest/
'data'

Comment: @jack022, please use /ajtest   ,don't go with this  /ajtest/

Comment: Look like i can't, here is why: "You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/ajtest/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202332/discussion-between-kabali-and-jack022).

Comment: add # in this line parameters={'data': $('#text_box').val()}

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `name` attribute to `<input type="text">`

from jquery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string,
>   the element must have a name attribute.

Add name attribute as,

```
<form method='post' id='test'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="value">
  <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
  <div id='message'>Initial text</div>
</form>
```

Here is demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nawarkhede/ajfvs58c/2/
. I can see data is being passed.

Comment: Fair enough, but then what should i edit in my ajax request?

Comment: Ok, but i also need to edit something in the ajax request. My django client still doesn't see the value that i submit